# Selection sort CLRS - Correctness of the reasoning

Tags: algorithm, selection-sort, big-o, clrs

I'm a self-taught computer science student.
Now I'm reading CLRS and I did the 2.2-2 exercise, it's about Selection Sort.

> First array subscript is 1.

The pseudocode that I wrote is:

```
FOR i=1 to A.length - 1
    FOR j=i+1 to A.length
        IF A[j] < A[i]
            new_index=j
    IF new_index > i
        tmp = A[i]
        A[i] = A[new_index]
        A[new_index] = A[i]
```

My reasoning is:
the first loop test is executed n times (1, 2, 3 ... n). When i becomes n the loop stops. So line 5 is executed (n-1) times and so on.

Then I think that the second loop test is executed (n^2 + n - 2)/2 times. When initial j = 2, it assumes: 2, 3, 4, 5 ... (n + 1), the loop test is executed n times, when j = 3 the loop test is executed (n - 1) times and so on. So when j = n the loop test is executed 2 times.

For this reason the second loop test is executed:
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n = [(n-1)*(n+2)] / 2 = (n^2 + n - 2) / 2.
So the inner if of the second loop is executed: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (n-1) = [(n-1)*n] / 2.

Before this written I read a lot of hypothetical solutions but no one is equal to mine. So I'd like to know if my reasoning is wrong.

I hope that I written all details in good form.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocode is right and your analysis is along the right lines, but your solution has some mistakes in its reasoning.

---

#### Some Tips

> Then I think that the second loop test is executed *(n^2 + n - 2)/2 times*

It's executed n(n-1)/2 times. See the solution below.

> When initial j = 2, it assumes: 2, 3, 4, 5 ... *(n + 1)*, the loop test is executed *n* times,

Remember the code is: `FOR j=i+1 to A.length`, so when the inner for loop starts at j = 2, it goes up to j = A.length, i.e. it goes up to j = n. In other words, it executes repeatedly for j = 2, 3, 4, ..., n and so executes a total of *n - 1 times*, not *n times*!

> For this reason the second loop test is executed: 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n = [(n-1)*(n+2)] / 2 = (n^2 + n - 2) / 2. So the inner if of the second loop is executed: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (n-1) = [(n-1)*n] / 2.

Suppose the body of the if statement of the second loop is *always* executed (the if condition is *always* true), then it should execute the same number of times as the second loop test. So I don't follow your reasoning here. And as for the summation, to find number of iterations, you need to add up the following:

- j = 1: executes (n-1) times
- j = 2: executes (n-2) times
- j = 3: executes (n-3) times
- ...
- j = n: executes 1 time

So you need to add up: (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1 = n(n-1)/2

---

#### Solution

1. The inner for loop executes *exactly* C(n, 2) = n(n-1)/2 times. The loop produces all pairs (i,j) such that 1 <= i < j <= n – which from combinatorics is *n-choose-2*, or C(n, 2).
2. The if statement body (`new_index=j`) executes *at most* n(n-1)/2 times – we don't know exactly how many because we don't know what the values in `A` are – so we don't know how many times `A[j] < A[i]`. It could execute zero times (consider the case when the array is sorted). But nevertheless, we find an upper bound by assuming the condition is always true. In this worst case, the if statement's body executes the same number of times as the inner for loop – which from the previous bullet point is n(n-1)/2
3. By similar reasoning, the other if statement body (the one performing the swap) executes *at most* n times.

So overall, the algorithm performs exactly n(n-1)/2 iterations of the inner for loop iterations having ϴ(1) work – and exactly n iterations of the if statement performing a swap in ϴ(1) time. This gives a time complexity of ϴ(n^2).